# Printer will not print from any PC

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, printer, network-printer

I am having an issue with a printer on our network. It is a Sharp MX-2310U printer. Our network can see the printer and we can access the printer's webpage but it will not print whatsoever on any computer.

Things I have tried;
Checked the Driver - It is on it's correct driver.
Checked the port - It is on the correct port.
I can print a test page ONLY from the printer webpage.
I have removed and re-added the printer.
Checked it's settings.
Pinged the printer - pinged successfully.

I am not sure what else to try as this is happening to all computers.

Any ideas on what I can do to get this sorted, maybe something I haven't tried yet?

Any help is very much appreciated.
Thanks
Ethan

Comment: Please supply information how HOW the port is configured. There are several ways this can be done. Windows has at least 4 versions by default (more can be installed) and most printers can do at least 2. We can't guess form your information if the correct combination is used.

Comment: Looking at the port settings for the printer it is using LPR protocol and it doesn't have SNMP Status enabled. If I am missing anything let me know.

Comment: Lpr... Ok. Are you sure the queue-name is set correctly ? This can be case-sensitive in some printers.  Most Sharp models use "lp" without the quotes.

Comment: And obviously LPD must be enabled in the printer too.

Comment: LPD is enabled also, and the LPR queue name is "lp" so that doesn't seem to be an issue.

Comment: Mmmhh. That's odd. Can you (if not already done so) enable the optional Windows feature "LPR Port Monitor". This install another LPR client port option in addition to the "TCP/IP Printing Port". Then reconfigure the print-queue to use a port setup with the other LPR variant. In my experience some printers (depending on their internal LPD version) work better with the LPR Monitor than with the LPR version of the TCP Printing Port.

Comment: Still nothing, also when I print a test page to the printer it goes into the print queue and says spooling and printing and then leaves in the space of a second. whether this is of any help I'm not sure.

Comment: It it spools and disappears the printer is accepting the job. Look for the problem inside the printer. Not in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue with a MX-2610N with Win10 machines, print jobs sent to the device cause it to whirl and spin up like its going to print but nothing actually happens.

As Tonny indicated the problem was the Sharp MX-2610N in my case the device was still set on an old domain and DNS. IP was correct but as soon as I reset the domain and DNS the printer now worked.